# Django dynamic models disappear after restarting server

Tags: django, django-models

In my Django app I create a bunch of models at runtime dynamically. The models are created fine and they are registered properly. However, when I restart the server that my app is running on, the models disappear. The data stays in the database but there is no sign of the models I created. I tried recreating the models with `inspectdb` but since they are not static models like `inspectdb` creates, it does not work out properly. I have also tried registering them at database connection, but the issue is that they are not even known as models to begin with.

Does anyone know how I can keep my models after restarting?

Comment: that is strange behavior.How did you install the apps in your admin.py file? Can you show some code

Comment: @hansTheFranz I have my apps in settings base.py, in my admin.py I have nothing super related to this, only the admin options for my other models.

Comment: Ok I think I don't quite get what you mean. The code you wrote is deleted? Like the files on your computer are empty? Or you go into 127.../admin and can't see the models anymore?

Comment: I'm not sure what you expected to happen. Django doesn't store a model registry in the database (that's what the code + migration history is for). If you're going to declare a model at runtime, it will not persist.

I'm assuming re-registering the models (after restarting) allows you to access the data?

Comment: @Kye I tried to use the `get_models` function and register all the models after restarting, but the issue is that the models do not persist as you mentioned. How do you suggest I obtain the information for registering the models?

Comment: @hansTheFranz When I go to 127.../admin I can't see the models anymore. That's right. Also in my admin.py I don't have much code related to my dynamic models. So we can assume it's empty.